# Application get freezes when opening Form in ShowDialog in Task ContinueWith TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext

Tags: wpf, task-parallel-library, showdialog

In my WPF application, I'm using Task Parallelism to enhance the multitasking and UI responsiveness, but I am facing an issue of application freeze.

Following is the code I'm using:

MainForm.cs

```
Storyboard board = (Storyboard)this.FindResource("StoryboardLoadingAnimation");
board.Begin(this, true);
this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    { 
        //Long Running Task 
    }).ContinueWith((prev) =>
    {
        if (board != null)
        {
            board.Stop(this);
        }
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;

        this.popupOverlayHelper.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Adding overlay on main form by giving opacity and background color to popupOverlayHelper element              

        NotificationPopup notification = new NotificationPopup(this, NotificationsType.Info); // Another WPF Window form 
        notification.Owner = this;
        notification.ShowDialog();
        this.popupOverlayHelper.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

NotificationPopup.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Application.TrackOFF_NotificationPopup"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Application"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Title="NotificationPopup"
    WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
    FontFamily="/TrackOFFApplication;component/Fonts/#Segoe UI"
    Width="1024px" Height="640px" Background="{x:Null}"
    MouseLeftButtonDown="NotificationPopup_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <Grid Margin="240px,68px,0,0">
        <!--Other xaml code to show notification -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

NotificationPopup.xaml.cs

```
void NotificationPopup_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DragMove();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Helper.WriteLogEntries(ex, "NotificationPopup => NotificationPopup_MouseLeftButtonDown");
    }
}
private void CloseMe(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.Close();
        if (IsParentToShowAgain)
            (ParentPopup as Window).Show();
        if (IsOverlayToKill)
        {
            (ParentPopup as MainForm).popupOverlayHelper.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Helper.WriteLogEntries(ex, "NotificationPopup => CloseMe");
    }
}
```

This NotificationPopup don't have any complex functionality in it, it just shows the notification message to the user and on click of X on top right corner "CloseMe" function gets call which closes the popup and render MainForm again.

The issue here is,
The application get freeze when notification pop up remains open for more than few seconds, or I play with pop up (like dragging pop up screen on here to there).

Interestingly, if I remove the Task from the code then application not freezes and works as expected.
But I seriously don't want to remove Task from the code as it has Long Running task to execute and I want to free the UI thread and show the animation to the user until the Long Running task finishes his work.

Your valuable feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: For this kind of operation you should probablyuse Background Worker

Comment: Maybe you have to read [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) article first.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` here. `await` your long running task and the remainder of your method will run on the captured context.

I'm assuming your code came from `Window_Loaded` or similar event handler:

```
private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Storyboard board = (Storyboard)this.FindResource("StoryboardLoadingAnimation");
    board.Begin(this, true);
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;

    //offload work from UI
    await Task.Run(() => {
        //Long Running Task 
    });

    //work is complete, execution returns to UI context
    if (board != null) {
        board.Stop(this);
    }
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;

    this.popupOverlayHelper.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Adding overlay on main form by giving opacity and background color to popupOverlayHelper element              

    NotificationPopup notification = new NotificationPopup(this, NotificationsType.Info); // Another WPF Window form 
    notification.Owner = this;
    notification.ShowDialog();
    this.popupOverlayHelper.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: Is there any problem to use Task.Factory.StartNew for big computational task, and then use ContinueWith on UI thread for handling response and updated UI elements.

Comment: Yes there are a number of problems properly using `StarNew` see [StartNew is Dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). There's very little good reason to use the older continuation based techniques when `async/await` generally makes code:  more maintable, easier to reason about and easier to read.